# Help with Solving a System of ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

A friend of mine came up with this system of ODEs :

$$g \cos \theta - \frac{C}{1 - \sin \theta} \frac{d^{2}x}{dt^{2}} = \frac{d^{2}x}{dt^{2}} (1 - \sin \theta) - (x - R (\theta - \theta_{0})) \left( \frac{d \theta}{dt} \right)^{2} \\ - g \sin \theta = (x - R (\theta - \theta_{0})) \frac{d^{2}\theta}{dt^{2}} + 2 \frac{dx}{dt} \frac{d \theta}{dt} - R \left( \frac{d \theta}{dt} \right)^{2} 
- \frac{d^{2}x}{dt^{2}} \cos \theta$$

($x(t)$ and $\theta(t)$ are the desired functions and the rest are all constants.)

[image]

I have tried it on Mathematica but it seems the derivative diverges at all values of $t$. Can anyone help?

Comment: What do you want to show?

Comment: It seems that you didn't assign any values to the variables $g$, $d$, and $R$.

Comment: **I have tried it on Mathematica** if you ask on Mathematica forum may be someone there can help with the code.

Comment: @Ilbant I assigned values and it still says it has non-numerical values and 1/0 error.

Comment: @Meowdog I am trying to find $x(t)$ and $\theta(t)$, or at least plot it if it is impossible to find a closed solution.

Comment: Are you running into issues by using reserved capital letters that are symols as in Select[WolframLanguageData[], 
  StringLength[CanonicalName[#]] == 1 &] // CanonicalName

Comment: As Moo mentioned, $C$ is also a built-in function of Mathematica. Change the variable and it should work